# Is it possible to implement further divisibility to Bitcoin in the future?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, economic-theory, reward-schedule, divisibility

I’ve been wondering if it would be possible to modify Bitcoin to further split sats so that emission could theoretically continue asymptotically beyond 2140. I’m not an experienced coder (currently learning) so haven't tried to read and understand Bitcoin code yet, but I understand that 64-bit memory is sufficient to store any possible balance of what will eventually be 2.1 quadrillion sats, with perfect accuracy and with 1 bit buffer. With only 1 bit of buffer, if sats were further divided into micro or nano sats and beyond, it wouldn’t be possible for 64-bit machines to accommodate all possible balances down to the smallest denomination without potential rounding errors. However, by the turn of the next century, I imagine 128-bit or even 256-bit machines will be standard (or qubit machines), so in that case would it be possible to further subdivide sats into microsats/ nanosats to allow emission to continue in theory forever, guaranteeing block rewards for miners? It seems more elegant and dynamic to have a target that’s perpetually approached but never reached.

Also, if global M2 money supply is, say $100T, this is 10 quadrillion cents, which means that if Bitcoin's 2.1 quadrillion sats completely replaced all the world's money each sat would be worth nearly 5 cents, making Bitcoin *less* divisible than dollars. Combining this with the notion that in a true market economy, the cost of goods and services should reduce over time due to innovation (admittedly offset by scarcity of resources), we may reach a point where Bitcoin is insufficiently divisible to pay for the lowest priced goods and services available, similar to how pieces of gold were impracticably small to manage in the payment of low-cost items.
I suppose further divisibility could be implemented on Layer 2 such as Lightning, but channel balances would still need to be settled on-chain to the nearest sat.

Comment: Hey b0d, we already have a few topics that are closely related to your question. Could you please check these out and see if they answer your question? If not, could you please edit your post to clarify how your question is different from the others and let us know to reopen the topic?